# How to find closest point of LineString to a coordinate in python

Tags: python, point, shapely

I have the following code...

```
import osmnx as ox
latitude = 51.217220
longitude = 4.418535

p = ox.Point(latitude, longitude)
line = ox.LineString([(4.4203843 , 51.2154117), (4.420431, 51.2159018), (4.4204697, 51.2163913), (4.4204833, 51.2166588),  (4.4204243, 51.2168076), (4.4203641, 51.2169564), (4.4203409, 51.2170063), (4.4202929 ,51.2171074), (4.4202355 ,51.2171806), (4.420205, 51.2172067), (4.4201654, 51.2172246), (4.4201077 ,51.2172411), (4.4200562 ,51.2172511), (4.4194807 ,51.217338), (4.4190475 ,51.2174025), (4.4179023 ,51.2175729), (4.4178548 ,51.21758), (4.4177154 ,51.2176008)])
np = nearest_points(line, p)[0]
print(np)
```

However the **output** becomes

> POINT (4.4203843 51.2154117)

And this is clearly not the closest point, to my point from this LineString.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you accidentally reversed your latitutude and longitude fields, per chance?

Answer (score 0):

What is `nearest_points`? Your code snippet isn't reproducible but here's a good guess: the coordinates in your LineString are represented as (longitude, latitude) but your Point is represented as (latitude, longitude).